# como puedo evitar que el recorrer un item este se empalme con otro y se repitan los resultados?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, .net, servicio

estoy creando un servicio de windows (soy nuevo en esto) tengo un metodo que lo que hace escribirme en un archivo de texto algunas cosas(no dare mucho detalle de eso) ese metodo se va a llamar determinadas horas del dia , el problema aqui es que por cada item que hay el array este me lo escribe varias veces cuando yo deseo que no sea asi un ejemplo esto me escribe en mi archivo de texto:

- importando 1 de 10
- importando 1 de 10
- importando 1 de 10
- importando 2 de 10
- importando 2 de 10
- importando 2 de 10

etc.....
si obervan pueden ver que el 1 y el 2 se repiten 3 veces , por que sucede esto? por el numero de elementos que tiene el arreglo si este tiene 3 , se repetira 3 veces el texto por el recorrido , solo que en mi codigo son mas  5 veces , al principio crei haberlo solucionado por que cree una variable boleana que se llama "YaPaso" y esta incia en false , entonces hay una validacion que verifica si esta en false , si se cumple pues ejecutara lo que hay adentro del if y esta sobreescribe la variable en true para evitar que el siguiente item a iterar se empalme , pero el problema aqui es que si hay una hora siguiente despues de ese item ya no vuelve a entrar por que la variable se sobreescribio a true y ya no esta en false y por eso no entra en el if alguna idea de que puedo hacer para evitar que se repitan las cosas es decir , busco que el recorrido de items se empalme uno con el otro , para evitar que el contenido del archivo de texto se escriba varias veces por el numero de items del arreglo , cabe decir que en el metodo de Procesar() se llama al metodo de GenerarCopiado() el cual se encarga de realizar ese archivo de texto adjunto codigo:

```
 private void Procesar()
    {
        //aqui es donde se inicia el proceso cada cierto tiempo
        bool YaPaso = false;
        var A = TimeSpan.Zero;
        int TiempoADormir = 0;
        bolCorrer = true;
        int intIntervaloCorto = miConfiguracionVO.IntervaloCorto * 1000;
        DateTime Tiempo = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(3);
        int _Tiempo = Tiempo.Second;
        int intPoleoIntervalo = _Tiempo * 1000;
        while (bolCorrer == true)
        {
            try
            {

                //Manda classe que genere algo
                //this.ClaseTest();
                //manda a llamar al proceso a las 
                //Thread.Sleep(TiempoADormir);

                //se crea una instancia de la clase timercallback que esta sirve para
                //manejar el metodo que se adjunta junto a un temporizador , pasandole por 
                //parametro al constructor nuestro metodo que queremos que ejecute , 
                //posteriormente se crea un arreglo de date time con las fechas que queremos
                //que mande a llamar a nuestro metodo de GenerarCopiado , del dia de hoy , 
                //añadimos las hora y el minuto que queramos que se ejecute ,posteriormente
                //se itera sobre las horas en ese arreglo para despues crear un intervalo de 
                //tiempo restando la hora actual , menos la hora que este en el item recorrido
                //posteriormente utilizamos la variable boleana con el nombre de "YaPaso" esta 
                //iniciara en false , y posteriormente se evaluara si esta en false para poder
                //realizar la llamada al metodo de generar copiado , una vez que lo hace se sobre
                //escribe nuestra variable a true , esto se hace con el fin de evitar texto duplicado        

                TimerCallback tiempo = new TimerCallback(GenerarCopiado);
                DateTime[] horasEjecucion = new DateTime[]
                {
                    DateTime.Today.AddHours(10).AddMinutes(38),
                    DateTime.Today.AddHours(10).AddMinutes(51),
                    DateTime.Today.AddHours(18).AddMinutes(28),
                    DateTime.Today.AddHours(18).AddMinutes(30),
                    
                };

                foreach (var hora in horasEjecucion)
                {
                    TimeSpan TiempoHastaEjecucion = hora - DateTime.Now;

                    //YaPaso = false;
                    if (YaPaso == false)
                    {
                        if (TiempoHastaEjecucion > TimeSpan.Zero)
                        {
                            YaPaso = true;
                            Timer temporizador = new Timer(tiempo, null, TiempoHastaEjecucion, TimeSpan.FromHours(24));
                        }
                    }

                }

                //GenerarCopiado();
                //bolCorrer = false;

                
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                string strMensaje = "El servicio se ha detenido por acumulación de errores.";
                if (this.ManejaExcepcionProcesar(ex, strMensaje) == false)
                {
                    miServiceController.Stop();
                    break;
                }
            }

        }

        //bolCorrer = true;
    }
```

Comment: Considero que el ejemplo está incompleto. Por un lado dices que genera un resultado con el texto "importando x de y", y el código que incluyes en ningún lugar imprime o tiene el texto "importando"... considera reducir el ejemplo a un [mcve]. Recuerda que es importante que sea **completo**, es decir, que el código que incluyes genere el resultado que mencionas.

Comment: okey mira , ya existe un metodo que se encarga de escribir el "importando x de y" tal como lo mencione anteriormente , bueno quizas no me explique bien , en resumen lo que hace ese metodo es llamar a otro metodo que en este caso es "GenerarCopiado()" en determinadas horas

Comment: Solo intento ayudar, por eso te refiero al artículo de ayuda: [mcve] con el énfasis en _completo_ (es importante también que sea mínimo y que sea verificable). Un saludo. No puedo hablar por todos los miembros de la comunidad, pero yo, para responder una pregunta como esta, suelo leer el código y hacer una ejecución mental, o incluso lo pego en un proyecto en el  IDE, lo ejecuto y lo depuro, hasta entender dónde está el problema. Espero que alguien más pueda ayudarte con el código que publicas. Un saludo.